# greping a specific regex

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to print out every string that starts with three 0's, ends with three 1's and has zero or more 0's in between.

I was given a file with one large string, with XXX separating the different string I needed to check.

I used sed to break up the string into separate lines wherever there is XXX, but I am trying pipe it into a grep with a specific regular expressions to display only the patterns that I want.

```
sed "blah blah" | grep 000*111
```

This displays strings like "1", "111", "000". What wold the regex be to get this specific pattern? Or can I not use grep with a regex like this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
sed "blah blah" | fgrep '000*111'
```

`$ whatis fgrep`

> fgrep (1)            - print lines matching a pattern

aka literal, not regex

Comment: Doesn't fgrep take filenames for input?

Comment: Like usual grep : file or [tag:stdin]

Comment: And all these years I thought it meant `grep -f` and just didn't work very well....